# ios app is crashing

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

I'm having a problem with my app crashing. The main root controller is a tab controller. inside the tab controller i have 4 buttons that have a nav controllers hooked up to them. inside the nav controller, i have a table controller with a few cells. when you click a cell, it takes you to a view controller. now when i click on the cell and it takes me to the view controller. when i click on the back arrow on the nav controller, it takes me back to the table view, which is great, but when i click on a new cell, the app crashes. everytime i click a cell, go back, and click another cell, the app crashes. what am i doing wrong? i think i too care of all my releases. not sure though.

Theres an error I get when I run the program. It reads:

> Book Nav Controller (Medical How To's) has it 'NIB Name" property set to 'BookTableViewController.nib', but this view controller is not intended to have its view set in this manner.

I'm also getting setText is deprecated on this code:

```
cell.text = [breakdownArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

What do I change it to?

Also My didSelectRowAtIndexPath code is:

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (self.bookDetailViewController == nil); {
    BookDetailViewController *aBookDetail = [[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailView" bundle:nil];
    self.bookDetailViewController = aBookDetail;

    [aBookDetail release];

}

bookDetailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%Breakdown" , [breakdownArray objectAtIndex:row]];

Surviving2012AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.breakdownNavController pushViewController:bookDetailViewController animated:YES];

[delegate release];

}
```

Comment: You didn't mention anything about your platform/OS/framework/programming language. Please add more details. You can improve your question skills a lot by following this guide: tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Please format the code, put proper tags and a proper question title.

Comment: To get rid of the deprecated method warning, use cell.textLabel.text instead of cell.text. Also, do NOT call [delegate release]

Comment: ... and it can't get up!

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.text = [breakdownArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Should be:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [breakdownArray objectAtIndex:row];

bookDetailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%Breakdown" , [breakdownArray objectAtIndex:row]];
```

Should be:

```
bookDetailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [breakdownArray objectAtIndex:row]];
```

If you're calling this from one of the viewControllers in the tabBarController, then this:

```
Surviving2012AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.breakdownNavController pushViewController:bookDetailViewController animated:YES];
[delegate release];
```

Should be:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bookDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

And if it's still crashing after that, then you'll need to post how you're defining:

bookDetailViewController in your .h file, and the contents of your viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad methods.

Answer (score 0):

As for your deprecated method:

change it to :

```
cell.textlabe.text = [breakdownArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

And I dont get the hang of this:

```
 Surviving2012AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.breakdownNavController pushViewController:bookDetailViewController animated:YES];

[delegate release];
```

You said that you have a navigationController in every tab? Then why don't you use it?

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bookDetailViewController


animated:YES];
```

Comment: i do use the nav controller. i have a table inside the nav controller. i click a cell. it takes me to a table view. then i pressed back on the nav and when i click a new cell. the app crashes.

Comment: Y I was just saying, that I don't think that you have to create an extra navController, because you could have one in your class already. But I don't know your code and if things work out this way, better don't change it ("never change a running system" ^^). But take a look at my comment above and add the autorelease to prevent memoryleaks

Answer (score 0):

Apple's iOS Reference Library -- available right there in Xcode under Help->Developer Documentation -- very clearly lays out what to replace the deprecated .text property with: **[.textLabel and .detailTextLabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW56)**.

Answer (score 0):

definitely don't call release on the delegate.
you only call release on an object when you have used a method on it which contains:
alloc/init, copy, new or retain. otherwise you are likely releasing an autoreleased instance, which will cause it to crash.

fix this, if it still happens, post your results, and we will have another look.

Comment: yup it stopped crashing!! thanks! but will this cause like a memory leak or something later on while using the app?

Comment: you could just use an autorelease call by changing code to: Surviving2012AppDelegate *delegate = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]autorelease];
By this your program handles the release.

Comment: it wont cause a leak because it is an autoreleased object. if it had new copy or alloc/init in the title then you would take ownership of the object and have to worry about managing the memory.if you dont own it, then dont release it. everything you need to know about memory management can be found here:http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/